# Set Attribute value of an element in protractor

Tags: angular, webdriver, protractor, appium

I have the following html

```
<ion-input class="nick-name-input input input-md ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched" name="nickname" type="text" ng-reflect-name="nickname" ng-reflect-model="my nickname" ng-reflect-type="text" style=""></ion-input>
```

I need to set the value of `ng-reflect-model` attribute for this element in protractor.
Basically, I need to clear the already present value in `ng-reflect-model` attribute.

Comment: Was the answer provided helpful or do require any additional assistance?

Answer (score 2):

**Approach 1 - executeScript**

You can use **executeScript** to send javascript code directly to the browser.
Read more on it here 
https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.executeScript

Just replace *hello* with whatever you want to insert into the element and pass that element as the *reqElement* in my example.

```
let reqElement = await element(by.css('.nick-name-input'));
await browser.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('ng-reflect-model','Hello');", reqElement);
```

**Approach 2 - Refresh using protractor.key.backspace**

Alternatively if the reason you are doing this is to have your changes reflected in the DOM you can create a function like this. This will clear and text and should refresh the DOM so the blank value will take affect in the ng-model-attribute

```
let clearTextAndModel = async function (reqElement) {
    await reqElement.clear();
    await reqElement.sendKeys('a');
    await reqElement.sendKeys(protractor.Key.BACK_SPACE);
}
```